# how to change textbox background color through javascript?

Tags: javascript

my javascript-

```
function validate_loginform(loginform) 
{
var uid = loginform.uid.value;
var pass = loginform.pass.value;
if(uid == "") 
  {

    color('uid');       
    return false;
  }
if(pass == 0) 
  {
    color('pass');
    return false;
  }

return true;
```

}

```
function color(traget)
{
var targetbox = document.getElementById(target);
targetbox.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

but background color is not getting changed even it is not returning `fasle` value. if I remove the `color('uid');` nad put `alert("user name required");` then this script is working fine.Whats wrong?
**it backgroundColor in actual program I just missed it here only**

Comment: `backgroungColor` should be `backgroundColor`, but maybe just a typo?

Comment: So many typos, check function color(traget) for starters!

Comment: it backgroundColor in actual program I just missed it here only

Comment: What about in function color(traget)? Is that just a typo here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont call color function, change color inside if condition like-

```
if(uid == "") 
  {     
    //alert("You must enter User ID.","error");
    loginform.uid.style.borderColor='red';
    loginform.uid.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Seems to change border color. Not background color as asked for.

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery you could try this:

```
 $("#textbox").css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo?

```
backgroungColor
         ^
```

## Update

Typo?

```
function color(traget)
               ^^^^^^
{
var targetbox = document.getElementById(target);
```

Seriously, actual code does matter.

Comment: its backgroundColor in actual program I just missed it here only

Answer (score 2):

Beware your spelling. It should be "target", not "traget".

> function color(traget)

Answer (score 1):

You've spelt target wrong in your function header and background wrong in the last line of the function.

Comment: its backgroundColor in actual program I just missed it here only

Answer (score 1):

just remove the single quote (') from color('uid')

```
and write it as color(uid);
```

Comment: It's supposed to be a string there. <edit>S</edit>He's using getElementById() to retrieve the element.